# Creating an instance inside a handler function with parameter

Tags: javascript, extjs, handler

I have this:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow',{stuff that uses param});

Ext.define('widget.panel',{

stuff

handlerFn: function (parameter) { //parameter comes from Ext.pass(this.handlerFn,parameter)
Ext.create('MyWindow',{param: parameter}).show();
}

stuff
});
```

The button and its handler are defined inside the initComponent of the panel. When I made this without using Ext.define on the window and directly hardcoding it in the handler instead everything worked fine. However now it says param is not defined. How to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler has to be passed through Ext.pass(this.handlerFn, [parameter])

Also inside the Ext.define make sure you know what your scope is on every level and you will easily find the parameter on the 'window' level.